# generic trigger to capture table data for audit in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Need help to create a generic trigger to log all tables.

i have table named "system" and need to log it.

the log table name system_audit is created with all columns of "system" table along with additional three columns named
modified_dt,modified_by and modified_type.

modified_dt will be current_timestamp
modified_by will be the user
and modified_type specifies whether its insert,update or delete.(Need to capture new data for insert/update and old for delete)

How to write a function to capture the above said data. Also it needs to be dynamics, so that i can use it across all the tables in my schema

Note:  All audit tables contains the modified_dt,modified_by and modified_type as mandatory.

I got a couple of codes from the net, but it is not working, I was working on with oracle before, and new to postgres, not sure on how to code it properly.Please help

Comment: Dynamic SQL is done with PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE`  statement. If the audit table has the same columns with some extra ones in the beginning, you could use `SELECT modified_dt, modified_by, modified_type, *`. You want to design how to get rid of old data - perhaps partitioning. But you will have to write the code yourself.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/michelmilezzi/audit-trigger) help you writing the trigger.

Comment: @laurenz albe : only the audit table has these 'modified' columns.
Secondly what to put after *..how to insert new datas for insert and update and old for delete...

Comment: @michel :it's too complex I didn't understand the code.i want something simple

Comment: @MichelMilezzi : I have gone through the link before, however i need the table columns to be get populated dynamically..How to do that? any ideas?

Comment: See solutions [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html)  and [here](https://github.com/wingspan/wingspan-auditing) and [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) and [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) and [here](http://archive.is/DFZP0)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name would you mind making recommendation as to what would your choice be were to pick one of those solutions nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to create a generic function and its working fine.Thanks for the help.

```
create or replace function audit.fn__audit()
    returns trigger as 
    $func$
    declare
    col_name  text:='';
    audit_table_name text := TG_TABLE_NAME || '_audit';
    begin
     if TG_OP = 'UPDATE' or TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN 
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO audit.%1$I  SELECT ($1).*,current_timestamp,user,'''||TG_OP||'''',audit_table_name) using NEW;
    else 
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO audit.%1$I  SELECT ($1).*,current_timestamp,user,'''||TG_OP||'''',audit_table_name) using old;
     end if;
    return new;
    END $func$ 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name:thanks for reminding..I just did